# C++ Passing array to functions error: incompatible types in assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I know the question was already asked elsewhere, but I keep not getting what's wrong here. Maybe I'm doing something wrong because the two arrays are inside a structure.

(EDIT: I am getting the structure from some other code, and I cannot change it)

I'm trying to pass two arrays of float to a function, and then saving back the result of manipulation in the first array.

core.h:

```
typedef struct{
    //other stuff
    float m_vector[16];
} structure_t;

class CoreClass{
    private:
        structure_t s1;
        structure_t s2;

       float *MyFunction(const float *vDest, const float *vNew);
}
```

core.cpp:

```
#include "core.h"
#include "another_file.h"

void anotherFunction(){
    //....
    s1.m_vector = MyFunction(s1.m_vector, s2.m_vector); //error here
    //....    
}

float *CoreClass::MyFunction(const float *vDest, const float *vNew){
    return yet_another_function(vDest, vNew);
}
```

When I'm calling the function, however, I'm getting this error:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘float*’ to ‘float [16]’
```

For completeness, here is the function I'm calling, though it does not seem to do any trouble at compile time:

another_file.h

```
static __inline float *yet_another_function(const float *vDest, const float *vNew){
    float *tmp = new float[16];
    //tmp = matrix multiplication (vDest * vNew)
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<4;j++)
            for(int k = 0; 4; k++)
                tmp[i + j*4] += vDest[i + k*4] * vNew[k + j*4];

    return tmp;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you are assigning pointer to array. In C++ you can't assign pointer to array.

```
s1.m_vector = MyFunction(s1.m_vector, s2.m_vector);
  ^^ array   ^^ return pointer
```

You could use copy the return valute from `MyFunction` to `s1.m_vector`.
But why do you need to reassign value to `s1.m_vector` anyway? You could just make `MyFunction` function take a ref to `structure_t` and modify `m_vector` internally.

```
void MyFunction(structure_t& vDest, const structure_t& vNew)
{
    vDest.m_vector[0] = vNew.m_vector[0];
    //...
    vDest.m_vector[15] = vNew.m_vector[15];
}
```

Edit

```
yet_another_function(structure_t* t, structure_t& vDest, const structure_t& vNew)
{
    // blah blah
    t->m_vector[i + j*4] += vDest.m_vector[i + k*4] * vNew.m_vector[k + j*4];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I cannot use a ref it basically because I'm performing matrix manipulation and I need to update the old matrix values with the new ones.

Comment: use a ref to vDest is perfect for that solution! Note, first parameter is not const, so  you can modify its matrix.

Comment: I wrote matrix manipulation, I meant matrix multiplication. See my updated question.
How can I perform matrix manipulation without corrupting the initial matrix values?

Comment: Then you need to copy the return value of MyFunction and delete the memory allocated by MyFunction, if you want to do it that way.

Comment: I don't really like that solution, but I think I'll do like that, just like PorkyBrain suggested too, or find some other workaround.

Comment: you may want to write yet_another_function this way, see my updated answer, just pass in this pointer to yet_another_function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your returning a pointer to float and trying to save it to your array. structure_t.m_vector is an array not a pointer.

you could fix it like this:

```
float * temp = MyFunction(s1.m_vector, s2.m_vector);
for(int i=0; i<16;i++)
    s1.m_vector[i] = temp[i];
delete[] temp;
```

this is still quite error prone, if you new a different size other than 16 in yet_another_function you got a bug. As a general rule using std::array or std::vector and returning by value would be suggested. If you compiler supports c++ 11 move semantics returning by value will not be a performance penalty.

Comment: So, how should I write that? Anyway I seemed to understand that in C++ writing float[], float[16] and float * is basically the same.

Comment: when passed as arguments to a function they all turn into float *, but on the left side of operator = they are different.